# My program compiles and runs but does not do any of the 6 options in the switch statements and I cannot figure out why

Tags: c++

http://pastebin.com/Em641fNe

I believe the problem is in the binarySearch function, but I'm not entirely sure. First, I pick choice 1 and input values. Then, I pick choice 4 just to check it's there and that both the binary and the display function work, but it automatically displays the message: "That name does not exist in the array." 
Also, the Test Case Input is:

```
1
GoogleNexus7
GN7862
17
89.99
1
IPhone6
725365
5
349.99
1
MacbookAir
268748
12
599.00
5
6
```

---

```
void displayInfo(Product inventory[], int numProduct)
{
    int i;
    string name;
    cout << "Enter product name of product to find: ";
    cin >> ws;
    getline(cin, name);
    i = binarySearch(inventory, MAX_INVENTORY, name);
    if (i < 0)
        cout << "That name does not exist in the array.\n";
    else
    {
        cout << "Product Name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "Locator: " << inventory[i].locator << endl;
        cout << "Quantity: " << inventory[i].quantity << endl;
        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
        cout << "Price: " << inventory[i].price << endl;
    }
}
```

---

```
int binarySearch(Product inventory[], int size, string name)
{

 int first = 0,             // First array element
        last = size - 1,       // Last array element
        middle,                // Mid point of search
        position = -1;         // Position of search value
    bool found = false;

    // Flag

while (!found && first <= last)
{
    middle = (first + last) / 2;     // Calculate mid point
    if (inventory[middle].name == name)      // If value is found at mid
    {
        found = true;
        position = middle;
    }
    else if (inventory[middle].name > name)  // If value is in lower half
        last = middle - 1;
    else
        first = middle + 1;           // If value is in upper half
}
return position;
}
```

**(My program is a bit lengthy, but please, please, please, bear with me. I've worked as hard as I possibly can by myself and simply cannot. Haven't slept :/...Thank you in advance for helping)**

Comment: Please make a [MCVE] that still reproduces the error and post that code in your question.

Comment: When you find that the code is too long to be pasted directly into a question, and you have to resort to an external site like PasteBin, that should be your first clue that the code is too long and no one will want to read it all. You should have a look at how to prepare a [MCVE]. And get some sleep!

Answer (score 0):

Just some things I could find when checking the code:

You are passing `numProduct` to your `add` function by value and not by reference. Use refernces where the value might change inside the function.

You are not updating the `name` of your inventory entry in your `add` function.

Also in you shouldn't pass `MAX_INVENTORY` to your `displayInven` but `numProduct`.

Comment: To update my add function, would I put something like storage += inventory[numProduct]; would that update it? And that would go right before numProduct++

Comment: Again: The operation you do will make no difference to the external 'version' of `numProduct` if it is not passed in by reference. If passed by value, the function takes a local copy and modifies that, so the outside world does not see the changes.

Comment: Well, after that i fixed. Then, storage += inventory[numProduct]; ?

Comment: @user2495587 Have you tried to fix your program as I described it and tried to run it again? If you still don't get how to use a reference for `add`: You did it right for your `removeProduct` function (look for `&`).

Comment: @user2495587 Also we are not here to write code for you. What your program does and what it should do is up to you. If you have a specific question to a specific program - please ask. If you want a manual on how to write your code or actually someone to write it for you - bad luck, that's not what this page is for.

Comment: Yes, I made the changes suggested. Thank you. After wards, I inputted option 4 to display the information, but any product name that I type in it says "That name does not exist in the array."

Comment: @user2495587 Do you actually store the name now? In your `displayInfo`: Why do you call `binarySearch` with `MAX_INVENTORY`?

Comment: @user2495587 And you should totally learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: I changed MAX_INVENTORY to numProduct and i call binarySearch to find the information.

Comment: @user2495587 Did it work? Do you actually store the name? If you still don't store the name it won't work. This will be my last response to this topic, as I am not your private teacher. If you have specific question on why something doesn't work: Read the ["rules"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), create a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and open up a new question.